# How to setup DNS registration on CentOS 7 for IPv6

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, centos7

I have CentOS7 box and would like to setup static IPv4 and dynamic IPv6.
It joined to Windows domain via realmd & sssd; In the network we have radvd that adv prefixes and routes. Everything works well. BUT.

The host has no records (A/AAAA) in Windows DNS Server.

How I can setup CentOS7 to register static IPv4 and dynamic IPv6 on Windows DNS Server?  May be it's stupid question, but Windows has no similar "issues" and register on startup or interface up; Is't possible achieve the same behavior on Linux box?

Comment: If you joined the domain with `realm join` then it should already be registering in the DNS. How exactly did you join the machine to the domain? What is the content of `sssd.conf`?

Comment: You are right, hard day.
Sorry, it was a stupid question

Answer (score 1):

Michael Hampton, was right.
Usually IPv6 assigned address is stable therefore before adding a server to the domain you have to check if IPv6 configured and a box received IPv6; Right after join a box to domain, it will create a record in DNS Server with required permissions.

In case if statefull mode is use DHCP server has delegated rights to create a record in DNS server.